# android aQuery post send images to server C#

Tags: c#, android, http

Im trying to send several images from android client to C# server via http post with AQuery library.

```
urlport="http://192.168.100.139:1111";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("testimage", new File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUris.get(0))) );
aQuery
    .ajax(urlport,params,JSONObject.class,new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status){
            alert("post complete");//not working
        }
});
```

**C# HTTP Listener**

```
lstnr = new Server();
lstnr.url = "http://" + ipbox.Text;
lstnr.port = portfield.Text;
lstnr.Received += Server_Received_multipart;
lstnr.StartListen();
```

in Server.class I set delegate that runs in receiving loop, accepts Stream

```
class Server{
    ......
    public event EventHandler<Stream> Received = delegate { };
    ......
    public void Start(){
        string prefix = String.Format("{0}:{1}/", url, port);
        listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
        if (!listener.IsListening) {
            listener.Start();
            isListening = true;
            try
            {
                while (isListening)
                {
                    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
                    Stream postdata = request.InputStream;
                    Received(this, postdata);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Start() error: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Server_Received_multipart(object sender, Stream msg)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        //here want to handle stream and show images in window and save on disk
        MessageBox.Show("message received"); //this not working too

    }));
}
```

Before I made a fork where server accepts string with imagees in it encoded in base64/ works fine, but app crashes woth OurOfMemory error if send several images with size>3-4 Mb. Sorry if grammatic not good, Im russian